# Semantic-Ui-React label color inverted

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I try to use label in semantic-ui-react. However, its color is inverted like below.

[image]

I expected below one.

[image]

My code is here:

```
<div className="resetBtn">
  <Button size="medium" onClick={this.onResetClick} primary>Reset dates</Button>
  <Label color="olive" pointing="below">Select the start date</Label>
</div>
```

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `basic` attribute for the label.

So instead of using `Label` as -

`<Label color="olive" pointing="below">Select the start date</Label>`

> Add *basic* attribute to `Label` as -

`<Label color="olive" pointing="below" basic>Select the start date</Label>`

Hope this helps. More info on basic attribute of Label component is available [here.](https://react.semantic-ui.com/elements/label/#types-pointing-colored)